# In a Rails 3 view, how do I detect an URL in a display string and format it as a link to that URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have user generated comments on my site.  If a user adds an URL in their comment, I'd like it to be formatted as a link and actually link to that URL.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rails has an [auto_link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-auto_link) text helper.

```
auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org and say hello to david@loudthinking.com")
# => "Go to <a href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org\">http://www.rubyonrails.org</a> and
#     say hello to <a href=\"mailto:david@loudthinking.com\">david@loudthinking.com</a>"

auto_link("Visit http://www.loudthinking.com/ or e-mail david@loudthinking.com", :link => :urls)
# => "Visit <a href=\"http://www.loudthinking.com/\">http://www.loudthinking.com/</a>
#     or e-mail david@loudthinking.com"
```

Comment: I've never heard about it. Great!

Comment: If you are using Rails 3.1+, please use rails_autolink as per nikstep

Comment: Can't find auto_link in the link you provided. Alternate documentation : http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link

Answer (score 8):

In rails 3.1 auto_link has ben removed, its now a standalone gem: https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the "auto_html" gem, see https://github.com/dejan/auto_html.

Disclaimer: Haven't used it myself yet, but it looks like it could do what you want.

Comment: It does more than what the question asked for, which is interesting, but requires a new gem. The auto_link is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend thinking about something like [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) for your comments. Then you can let the Markdown engine worry about stuff like this for you.

Answer (score -3):

First, you should define a regexp matching http strings, for example

```
IPv4_PART = /\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]/  # 0-255
REGEXP = %r{
    https?://                                                    # http:// or https://
    ([^\s:@]+:[^\s:@]*@)?                                        # optional username:pw@
    ( (([^\W_]+\.)*xn--)?[^\W_]+([-.][^\W_]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}\.? |  # domain (including Punycode/IDN)...
        #{IPv4_PART}(\.#{IPv4_PART}){3} )                        # or IPv4
    (:\d{1,5})?                                                  # optional port
    ([/?]\S*)?                                                   
}iux
```

then, suppose the comment body is str, you do:

```
str.gsub(REGEXP) do |m|
    link_to m, m
end
```

Comment: Rolling your own URL matcher is a really terrible idea--you **will** make a mistake. Use a library. :)